# What network traffic tool is out there, with a graphical interface?

Tags: networking

It does not have to be very fancy, i.e. like in this picture:

[image: Network History]

Comment: What does it need to do and why does that one not work well enough?

Comment: There is one tool, I forgot the name, which is for the terminal (ncurses based I think) and it shows signal strength and/or hearbeat for the current wifi connection... but it is displaying real-time values and does not show history...(I think it's called wavemon or similar)

Comment: do you have gnome-system-monitor already installed?

Comment: I run Lubuntu 15.04, not sure if it's installed.

Comment: @impalle Regarding the tool for the terminal, are you referring to [wavemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/wavemon.1.html)?

Comment: @Bart yep that's it!

Comment: @impalle OK, great, please accept my answer I just posted below, and glad to have been of help :)

Comment: @Bart thanks for your support but I needed a tool with GUI+history, which gnome-system-monitor has. This was the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the screenshot you posted is from **gnome-system-monitor**. You may try to install it:

`sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor`

Comment: He used tag lubuntu, and lubuntu doesn't have it installed by default. The screenshot could be taken from the internet.

Comment: Okay, so I installed the app. It seems pretty cool. Thanks!

Comment: A follow up question: can I add a keyboard shortcut (pressing CTRL+LEFT SHIFT+ESC) so that the system monitor starts?

Comment: It's not so trivial on lubuntu to add a shortcut, but you may try to follow the guide from here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard

Comment: Yes it's tricky... but I remembered I did it a while ago for Sublime Text, where I had to add some code to ".config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml"

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, which runs from the terminal and is ncurses-based as you note in your comment, is [wavemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/wavemon.1.html).